# Javascript: toggle class add or remove

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toggle

What I am going to do is:
When i click on mails button, 1st table is going to appear and hide the second table and when subscribers button is pressed, 2nd table has to appear and hide the 1st table.
But I am facing bugs like when i pressed 2nd button it will not hide the 1st table

```
<script>
    function toggle_display(id){
        if(id=='mails'){
            document.getElementById('mails').classList.remove('hidden');
            document.getElementById('subscribers').classList.add('hidden');
        }
        if(id=='subscribers'){
            document.getElementById('mails').classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById('subscribers').classList.remove('hidden');
        }
}</script>

<a href="javascript:toggle_display('mails');"><input type="button" class="btn" value="Mails"/></a>
<a href="javascript:toggle_display('subscribers');"><input type="button" class="btn" value="Subscribers"/></a>

        <div class="row well well-lg hidden" id="mails">
               <table class="col-sm-12" border="1px solid black">
               <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Name</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Email</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Phone</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Subject</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-3">Message</th>
               </tr>
               </table>
          </div>

          <div class="row well well-lg hidden" id="subscribers">
              <table class="col-sm-12" border="1px solid black">
                   <tr>
                      <th class="col-sm-2">ID</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-5">Email</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-3">Action</th>
                   </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing both tables on page load??

Comment: got it, you are using bootstrap so it will be fine. But your code is working fine.

Comment: From code it seems like @Ahmad you are using bootstrap? Right?

Comment: Yes, i'm using bootstrap. Now, code is working fine.

Comment: Thanks to all of you :]

Answer (score 0):

Use this,, It is working...

```html
<script>
    function toggle_display(id){
        if(id=='mails'){
            document.getElementById('mails').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('subscribers').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
        if(id=='subscribers'){
            document.getElementById('mails').style.display = 'none'; 
            document.getElementById('subscribers').style.display = 'block';
        }
}</script>
<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="toggle_display('mails');" value="Mails"/>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Subscribers" onclick="toggle_display('subscribers');"/>

        <div class="row well well-lg hidden" id="mails">
               <table class="col-sm-12" border="1px solid black">
               <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Name</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Email</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Phone</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Subject</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-3">Message</th>
               </tr>
               </table>
          </div>

          <div class="row well well-lg hidden" id="subscribers">
              <table class="col-sm-12" border="1px solid black">
                   <tr>
                      <th class="col-sm-2">ID</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-5">Email</th>
                      <th class="col-sm-3">Action</th>
                   </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: If you are using class hidden then use `.setAttribute("class", "hidden") ` and `.removeAttribute("class","hidden"); `